# Calculations at the bottom of each column

Tags: excel, rows, calculation

I am using an excel spreadsheet to keep track of some data.

[image]

I calculate median and quartile values for each column at the bottom of those columns (rows 15, 16, 17). However, I want to be able to keep adding new values into columns without changing the range of my median/quartile formula. I know I can select the whole column in my formula if I had the formula in a different cell than the column I am making calculations on.

I am wondering if there is a way to exclude the rows with my median and quartile formulas from my calculations. As I enter more data, those locations will also increase and I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: do you always know how many rows between your calculation cell and your last row of data?

Comment: because, for instance, if there were always two blank rows after the data and before the median, =median(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B2:B",text(row()-3,"#")))) should work.

Comment: this worked! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

So if we know the number of blank lines to be two, before we do the median, then `=median(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B2:B",text(row()-3,"#"))))`
works, by constructing the range of column B fed to the median function to be B2 through B + whatever number is 3 up from the row where the formula sits. For the IQR presumably 3 must be increased.